# Model Outputs 0 probability and 0 class for every observation

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, conv-neural-network

I am attempting to train a CNN using tensorflow. The architecture is structured as below.

```
# =============================================================================
# Build model architecture
# =============================================================================
model = Sequential()
# Convolution
model.add(Conv2D(8, (7,7), input_shape=(299, 299,3),padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2),padding='same'))

# Convolution
model.add(Conv2D(16,  (7,7),padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2),padding='same'))

# Convolution
model.add(Conv2D(16,  (7,7),padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2),padding='same'))

# Convolution
model.add(Conv2D(32,  (7,7),padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2),padding='same'))

# Convolution
model.add(Conv2D(32,  (7,7),padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2),padding='same'))

# Convolution
model.add(Conv2D(64,  (7,7),padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2),padding='same'))

# Convolution
model.add(Conv2D(64,  (7,7),padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2),padding='same'))

# Flattening
# this converts our 3D feature maps to 1D feature vectors
model.add(Flatten())  

# Full connection (dense)
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
```

After training the model I save the best performing weights.

```
checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(filepath='Documents/best_weights.hdf5', 
                               monitor = 'val_accuracy',
                               verbose=1, 
                               save_best_only=True)

# =============================================================================
# Train model
# =============================================================================
history = model.fit_generator(
                                train_generator,
                                steps_per_epoch=1000 // batch_size,
                                callbacks=[checkpointer],
                                epochs=epochs,
                                validation_data=validation_generator,
                                validation_steps=100 // batch_size)
```

I then use these weights to make a prediction for my test set to see how it was doing on individual observations.

```
all_path = "Documents/test/"
column_names = ["id","proba","label"]
pred_df = pd.DataFrame(columns = column_names)
for subdir, dirs, files in  os.walk(all_path):
    for file in files:
        img_name=file
        img_name=os.path.join(subdir,file)
        img_name = os.path.splitext(img_name)[0]
        img = image.load_img(os.path.join(subdir,file), target_size=(299, 299))
        x = image.img_to_array(img)
        x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
        images = np.vstack([x])
        classes = model.predict_classes(images, batch_size=10)
        probability = model.predict_proba(images, batch_size=10)
        class_1 = classes[0][0]
        proba = probability[0][0]
        l = [img_name, proba,class_1]
        l = np.array(l).reshape(1,3)
        column_names = ["id","proba","label"]
        temp_df = pd.DataFrame(l,columns = column_names)
        pred_df = pred_df.append(temp_df,ignore_index = True)
```

All of the observations have a 0 probability and 0 class, which is making me wonder what's going on? The observations in my test set are split evenly between the two classes, so it shouldn't just be learning to assign to one class as far as I can tell.

Edit: Below is my generator code.

```
# =============================================================================
# Specify model parameters and compile model
# =============================================================================

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='sgd',
              metrics=['accuracy'])


batch_size = 16
epochs = 5

# =============================================================================
# Add in data augmentations for train and test sets
# =============================================================================
# this is the augmentation configuration we will use for training
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1./255,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True)


test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'Documents/Training',  
        target_size=(299, 299),
        batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode='binary')  # since we use binary_crossentropy loss, we need binary labels

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'Documents/test',
        target_size=(299, 299),
        batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode='binary')
```

Comment: How does the generator code look like? Please include it and  all training code.

Comment: Updated the code above

Comment: That is not the whole code that defines the generator

Comment: Sorry, added in the other pieces I believe.

Comment: Your ImageDataGenerator is normalizing images (rescale = 1./255) while your code for testing is not applying the same scaling, that is why you don't get the same results

Comment: That does it, thank you.